5 high severity vulnerabilities in block editor
Will install @wordpress/scripts@19.2.4, which is a breaking change
node_modules/lighthouse/node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws
node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws
  puppeteer-core  11.0.0 - 22.11.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ws
  node_modules/lighthouse/node_modules/puppeteer-core
  node_modules/puppeteer-core
    @wordpress/scripts  >=20.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @wordpress/e2e-test-utils-playwright
    Depends on vulnerable versions of puppeteer-core
    node_modules/@wordpress/scripts
    lighthouse  9.6.1 - 11.5.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of puppeteer-core
    node_modules/lighthouse
      @wordpress/e2e-test-utils-playwright  >=0.9.1-next.5a1d1283.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of lighthouse
      node_modules/@wordpress/e2e-test-utils-playwright

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

i want to develop the block for the wordpress block editor this problem face here. any can help to fix

Did you run npm audit fix --force or not?

Latest version of @wordpress/scripts (at the time of writing) is 28.1.0. Any particular reason why you're trying to use version 19.2.4 instead of latest?

This error occurs when running @wordpress/scripts ^v27.9. Now that WordPress 6.6 has been released, we can update to ^v28, but that doesn't solve these dependency issues.
